# Persist Youtube Data API access token in Python desktop app

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, refresh-token

I have a Python application that accesses Youtube-Data-API v3.

After the program runs for an hour, it throws an error suggesting the access token has expired.

How can I persist the token for a longer period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now way to extend the time for `access token`. They get expired after an hour. The only way of using a token is to get a new token using `refresh_token` provided by the api.

First you get offline token by setting `access_type` to `offine` while authenticating  the user.

```
{
    'response_type': 'code',
    'client_id': 'client_id',
    'redirect_uri': '...',
    'access_type':'offline',
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
}
```

you will get `refresh_token`, `access_token`, `id_token` along with `expiry` and some other fields which you can save in you database and fetch later when needed.

Before using the `access_token` you check if it is valid

```
creds = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(access_token,refresh_token=refresh_token,id_token=id_token,token_uri=token_uri,client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret,scopes=scopes,expiry=expirytime)
if creds.valid == False:
  // Refresh to get the new token
  req =google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
  creds.refresh(req)
  // Now Save new Credentials from "creds" so that you can use later.
```

After verifying the `access_token` you can now query `youtube data api` requests

```
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    "youtube", "v3",credentials=creds)
req = youtube.videos().getRating(id="xxxxxxxxx")
resp =req.execute()
```

Comment: where did you find examples or documentation for those?

Comment: @cikatomo https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python
also https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/

Answer (score 0):

When you create O-Auth2 credentials, you need to select "Web App" which is what I think you're trying to create. (A website, correct?).

The "Desktop-App" option is for if you want to make a desktop application, not a website.

Desktop applications and web applications handle redirect uris differently, which is what's causing your issue.

Comment: No, it's a desktop app, I created it in python, and it runs on my computer. Would you know how to increase the time for a desktop app?